# Sending passwords securely via command line without being exposed in ps/wmic (Windows,Unix)

Tags: security, process, exec, wmic, ps

We have an *launcher* application in Windows and Unix which execs (starts application using exec system call) an application like RDP, putty, MSSQL. In order to invoke it, we pass parameters to such as username, password, IP.
Recently we found that, using wmic or ps one can find out what parameters have been passed it, thereby exposing sensitive information like passwords. 
Is there any way where we can either mask those passwords or hide the parameters all together.
Note: My launcher gets parameters from a some other service, so asking for password after invoking application is not a option! Passwords have to be passed to application as parameter.
Any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is not possible** (at least not on Linux, in a reliable way) to pass program arguments securely.

A possible workaround is to pass the name of a file (or some other resource - e.g. some "reference" to some database entry) containing that password, or use some other [inter-process communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) facility (e.g. on Linux, [fifo(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html), [shm_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html), [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html), [unix(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html), etc...) to pass these sensitive informations. You might also consider using environment variables (see [environ(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html) & [getenv(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getenv.3.html)).

On Linux look also into [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) to understand what it is able to show about processes - thru `/proc/1234/` for the process of pid 1234. Maybe you want [seccomp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seccomp) facilities.

On Unix, be aware of the [setuid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) mechanism -tricky to understand-. Use it carefully (it is the basic block of most security or authentication machinery such as `sudo`  and `login`) since a simple mistake could open a huge [vulnerability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vulnerability_(computing)).

For a software written to work both on Unix & Windows, I recommend passing the password in some file (e.g. in `/tmp/secretpassword`) and giving the name`/tmp/secretpassword` (or some `D:\foo\bar` on Windows)  of that file thru some program argument, and make sure to use wisely the file permission mechanisms to ensure that file is not readable by those who don't need it.

Comment: Note that using a hardcoded filename opens one up to symlink attacks on some systems. It's better to use whatever local equivalent to `mktemp` is available to create a unique name in a way that fails should anyone attempt to front-run the file's creation.