# How to hide command line arguments of a process started via subprocess?

Tags: python

Line example:

```
subprocess.Popen("any program", stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL, shell=True)
```

I will be glad for your help.

Experimented with the library

Comment: In general, you can't. The program being started can change its arguments after it finishes starting up, but you as the program that's calling it don't have that ability.

Comment: Also, you can't do that effectively when you use `shell=True`, because you're starting a shell and having _that shell_ start the child process; so even if you write the child process to hide its arguments (which again, isn't effective enough to be used for security purposes), the shell in between the two won't. (In some circumstances the shell may use an `execv`-family call to cause the child to take over its PID, but that's an implementation-defined optimization and can't be relied on)

Comment: There's a reason that tools like sshpass, psql, mysql, &c tell people not to provide passwords as command-line arguments; it's inherently insecure, and that has nothing to do with which language you're starting the tool from.

Comment: See also [Sending passwords securely via command line without being exposed in ps/wmic (Windows,Unix)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50960822)

Comment: i use java and run minecraft file through it, i don't have to decide above. is there any library for working with java and running?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the context well enough to provide a better answer. Why are you trying to hide arguments? Does minecraft take a password or other secret on its argument list? I'd _hope_ it would support an alternate, safer calling convention (like the other tools I mentioned above do; they allow passwords to be passed through environment variables, or through files, or through pipes/FIFOs/pre-opened file descriptors, etc).